# Nested ACF Repeater Showing Just One Value

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

Greetings – I need the third repeater here (`product_table_products`) to loop within the second repeater (`product_table_columns`).

Right now, the second repeater is returning (via the `$tcols` variable) only the very last field value because the second repeater loops until it’s done and then moves on to the next bit of code–the third repeater. I need this code to loop through the second and third repeaters as one.

I’ve tried moving the `endwhile` and `endif` lines all over the place in an attempt to make them loop together to no avail.

```
<?php if ( have_rows( 'product_table' ) ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'product_table' ) ) : the_row(); ?>

        <table>
    
        <h3><?php the_sub_field( 'product_table_title' ); ?></h3>
        
        <?php if ( have_rows( 'product_table_columns' ) ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_rows( 'product_table_columns' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                <?php $product_table_column_selected_option = get_sub_field( 'product_table_column' ); ?>
                <?php if ( $product_table_column_selected_option ) : ?>
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( $product_table_column_selected_option['label'] ); ?></th>
                    <?php $tcols = esc_html( $product_table_column_selected_option['value'] ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?> 
        
        <?php if ( have_rows( 'product_table_products' ) ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_rows( 'product_table_products' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                <?php $product_table_product = get_sub_field( 'product_table_product' ); ?>
                <?php if ( $product_table_product ) : ?>
                    <?php $tdata = get_field($tcols, $product_table_product->ID); ?>
                    <tr><td><?php echo $tdata ?></td></tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>      
        <?php endif; ?>

            </table>
            
    <?php endwhile; ?>      
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The reason it's only showing one value could be because the first repeater might only have one row, so it'd only loop once. And because it loops only once, you get just one value. Hope that makes sense.  I'd create an array for third repeater before the loop and push the values to it and then use it inside other repeaters.

Comment: Thanks for the response. On our test product page, there are three entries that would appear on the outer loop (product_table_product). I think we know why it is happening because we can echo the variable within the second repeater and all of the values appear. But we need to pass those values, which are names of ACF fields that the third repeater then displays their respective values. I think you're right that we probably need an array on the second repeater so we can loop through the values in the third. I've tried doing it based on docs but no love. (I'm learning PHP as I go...)

Comment: I ran out of room but it seems that if we were to move the first endwhile/endif under the third repeater, they would loop as one. It doesn't break the code but then nothing displays — even if I just put a random word anywhere inside the thrid loop. #confused :)